# Story of Sharangati

Tags: vaishnavism

There are two ways to attain Moksha:

1. Practice or take attainment in one own's hand.
2. Surrender or accepting oneself incapable, giving up self striving & surrender the fate to the Lord.

Sri Vaishnavism by Ramanujacharya aims at later one as a sole way to attain Moksha owing to incapability of Kaliyuga's people of self striving (Tapas) which they call Sharangati. I have found the following story based on Sharangati while listening a discourse. Would like to know the story along with the sources.

> Once In the Vaikuntha, Lord Vishnu suddenly prepared to go for Mrityuloka. On asking the reason by Goddess Lakshmi he told he was about to go there to save his devotee who has surrendered his life unto him. The devotee was  beaten by mob with stones. Within moments he came back. On asking by Goddess whether he saved him or not, Lord Vishnu answered in negation. On further enquiry by Goddess why he didn't went to Mrityulok to save his devotee he answered his devotee **picked up stones to save himself** so called off his visit.

As evident from the passage this story highlights the meaning of Sharangati. But at the same time, compels me to wonder whether this is inactivity in name of divinity or not? Are we not supposed to even save ourselves? - forms my second question.

Comment: There is only one way to attain moksha, knowing the self. And there is no other way.

Comment: @Rickross Of course, But I think Choice less awareness leads to Moksha. Sharangati makes one choice less at the time of death might be reason of attainment.

Comment: I heard the same story with Shiva in it

Comment: This is very likely a product of somebody's imagination with no scriptural basis. Vishnu leaving Lakshmi, when Krishna could simultaneously and separately entertain 16000 wives? Lakshmi asking her husband what happened like a human wife? Really? Nowadays even supreme God seems to have a day job and a housewife.

Comment: @user1952500 Scriptures are full of such whimsical stories. BTW i too thought the same.

Comment: @user1952500, maybe disbelieving scriptures is a product of *your* imagination..

Comment: @Fire, just put yourself in their position. If someone fell at your feet asking you to lend him money, and then started earning money by working elsewhere, would you still lend him ? by earning elsewhere, he has implicitly declared that he does not need your help.

Comment: @Rickross, 'knowing the self' is the 'goal', not the 'way'. Karma, Jnana, Bhakti yogas and Surrender are the 'ways'. Also, 'knowing the self' can mean 'kaivalya', which is not considered the supreme goal by many since it is kevalam (alone) svatmanubhavam.

Comment: @ram I understand. your words make sense.

Comment: @Fire. I am really interested in knowing what scriptures have this story.

Comment: @ram Knowing the self is the way and the only way. Both as per Vedas and the Agamas.

Comment: @Rickross, 'knowing' is not an action, so it cannot be a 'way'.. it is the goal, not the journey. and without making the journey (through karma,gnana,bhakti yoga or surrender), the goal (knowing the self) cannot be attained. You would be contradicting Bhagavad Gita otherwise.

Comment: Good question @Mr. Sigma